# Odd takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) Error Python

Tags: python

I am wondering why for the code shown below results in passing self to function?

```
class A(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self._t = ObjT()

  def Foo(self):
    self._Bar(50)

  def _Bar(self, num):
    self._t.function(num)
```

The call is:

```
a = A()
a.Foo()
```

Resulting in:

`TypeError: function() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: What happens if you omit `num` in `function`? It might not be designed to take any arguments. If you get an error, please tell us it.

Comment: My apologies I think I made the example too abstracted. The actual function was `def retweet(self, id)` from the `Twython` package. But the issue actually lies in having OAuth2 (read only) vs. OAuth1 access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that somewhere is a class called `ObjT` with a method called `function` that is not designed to accept an argument. I suspect the definition of `ObjT` includes this line:

```
def function(self):
```

Where it should be something like this:

```
def function(self, number):
```

Comment: Assuming I am unable to change ObjT how might I go about modifying this statement?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what it does. But if `ObjT.function` doesn't take an argument, then it expects to be called this way: `self._t.function()`.